# WINE and Windows named pipes

Tags: named-pipes, wine

Here is my problem:
I have a closed-source third-party Win32 application, which acts as a server for other programs via named pipes, i.e. it expects its clients to do smth like this:

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\$pipe_name$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, etc...);
// ...
TransactNamedPipe(h, buf, etc...);
// ...
CloseHandle(h);
```

This app runs perfectly in WINE, except that I can't communicate with it. So here is my question:

What exactly does WINE do when it is requested to open a pipe? Does it, say, map it to some FIFO file in ~/.wine/ or wherever? Is there **any** way to communicate with such program from a Linux application? Google doesn't know anything about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named pipes are hosted by the WINE server process. Requests are sent to this process by the WINE clients. For example, `CreateNamedPipe` uses a request like:

```
    SERVER_START_REQ( open_file_object )
    {
        req->access     = access;
        req->attributes = attr->Attributes;
        req->rootdir    = wine_server_obj_handle( attr->RootDirectory );
        req->sharing    = sharing;
        req->options    = options;
        wine_server_add_data( req, attr->ObjectName->Buffer, attr->ObjectName->Length );
        io->u.Status = wine_server_call( req );
        *handle = wine_server_ptr_handle( reply->handle );
    }
```

The server manages connecting the named pipe. Once a client and server have connected, the WINE server gets out of the way by sending an fd to the client. I think this fd is just an anonymous pipe created by the WINE server, one end being sent to the pipe server and one end to the pipe client.

Comment: Does that mean that it's only possible to communicate with Win app inside the Wine environment? I just don't understand how to "break the wall" between this environment and native Linux.

Comment: Yes, you will have to talk to the WINE server in some way in order to gain access to the pipe.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: It might be easiest to write your client as a Windows program and run it under WINE, or perhaps the Windows API from WINE can be easily linked to from a Linux program. These seem like the most straightforward approach, as you then have a documented interface to use.

Answer (score 4):

[Named Pipes](http://wiki.winehq.org/NamedPipes) in a wine official wiki

this article could help too: http://lkcl.net/namedpipes/namedpipes-emulation.txt

Comment: This is remote pipes. He is asking about local pipes.

Comment: "Named Pipes" (https://wiki.winehq.org/NamedPipes) is now an empty page.